# XenServer 6.5 Patch Installed But Missing

Tags: xenserver, update, patch-management, xencenter

I installed a few patches in my **XenServer 6.5** environment. After I installed the 3 patches I noticed that in XenCenter that my server is saying it needs patch **XS65ESP1021** installed.

I confirmed that **XS65ESP1021** is already applied to this server. **I tried installing the patch again, I tried cleaning the patch, destroying the patch and restarted the toolstack but its still saying it needs to be installed.** When I tried destroying the patch it said I cannot destroy it since it was already applied.

Now all of the servers in my pool have that arrow next to them (instead of the green light) indicating they need patches applied. I'm not sure what to do.

Other than reinstalling Xen, which I'd like to avoid, does anybody have experience with this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the solution to removing the duplicate patch: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX214780?_ga=1.144868401.488799848.1436816370